# Using openie to reproduce extractions as shown in (Angeli et. al)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have downloaded the Openie jar files including the model and have it running successfully. However, it is extremely basic out of the box not recognizing multiple clauses nor any examples as elucidated in its foundational paper "Leveraging Linguistic Structure For Open Domain Information Extraction." I would like to reproduce the extractions that are shown in the paper. Are there other models and a explanation of the configuration I need to implement to replicate these results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering when this would come up... Between the publication of the paper and the release of the code, CoreNLP moved its dependency parser from Stanford Dependencies to Universal Dependencies. Some of the examples in the paper now have incorrect dependency parses  (though some of these are fixed now!), and therefore these errors propagate to the OpenIE system.

However, these should be one-off errors. To test clause splitting, you can try a sentence like "Cats have tails, and dogs chase cats." and you should get both (cats; have; tails) and (dogs; chase; cats). And it should certainly work on most of the examples in the paper still. If not, let me know and I'll fix it!

Comment: Thanks for your  response. I can certainly get some clauses to split, though  I am having trouble with ones such as: "Born in Honolulu, Hawaii,  Obama is a US Citizen.

Comment: Yes, that's the most awkward one that now fails. If you remove the comma between Honolulu and Hawaii ("Born in Honolulu Hawaii, Obama is a US Citizen") then the parser gets the correct parse, and you should get the expected extractions. The version of the code in the upcoming CoreNLP release should have this fixed as well.

Comment: Thanks! It works. If it helps I can send you other phrases that aren't working. We can take this  offline if you'd like.  I can provide some QA as I'll be running a lot of text through this, NER, coreference and comparing to dependences.

Comment: More examples would be great, if you have them! Email is probably best: <last_name> <at> stanford.edu